# Vba Userform output on notepad popup

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub PrNotes_Click()
Dim fso As Object
Dim strPath As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object

strPath = TextBox1.Value & " Order Notes.txt"
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)

            oFile.writeline "Name : " & TextBox1.Value
            oFile.writeline "Contact : " & TextBox2.Value
            oFile.writeline "Email : " & TextBox3.Value
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
MsgBox ("Notes Generated Successfully in Documents Folder")
'Now this output should be on notepad instead of documents folder

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it you want to do?  Put the text into Notepad without writing it to the disk first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
MsgBox ("Notes Generated Successfully in Documents Folder")
'Now this output should be on notepad instead of documents folder
```

with

```
Shell "notepad.exe /W """ & strPath & """", vbNormalFocus
```

Warning: you have to know the encoding of the file at `strPath` to choose between `/A`, i.e. ASCII, and `/W`, i.e. Unicode.

See also [Notepad.exe command line options](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389?auth=1)  and [Shell at Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63)